# NetLogo: how to read values from a data set, assigning values at each tick?

Tags: file-io, netlogo

I'm modelling salmon population dynamics and I have a real data set about temperature and flow. I would like to assign a daily value of these two parameters during each tick, setting the first tick as the first day in the dataset and making it keep reading the file.

How can I do that?

Jacopo

Comment: How is the data represented in the file? csv? Can you give a small sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

NetLogo has fairly extensive IO capabilities for text files (and thus for CSV). You apparently have your data in a simple CSV file, so you will need to use these capabilities. For simple IO examples, see https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/notes/netlogo-intro.xhtml#file-based-io  There are also lots of examples of reading CSV files on the web (e.g., http://netlogoabm.blogspot.com/2014/01/reading-from-csv-file.html).  Unfortunately, NetLogo does not provide a CSV reader.

You suggest you would like to repeatedly read from the file. You will then have to leave the file open for the entire simulation. Each tick you can read in one line from each open file.

Unless it is a very large dataset, I would rather read in all the data into two global lists (e.g., `temparatures` and `flows`) at the very beginning.  Since you say you want to update the values each tick, use the current tick value to index into these lists.  E.g., `set temp item ticks temperatures`. (Here I assume you only use `tick` to advance the tick counters, so that you get successive integers. Also if you `tick` before you start reading data, you'll need to use `ticks - 1`.)

hth

Comment: Hi. My data are contained in two different datasets: one for daily temperatures and another one for daily flows since 2002. Basically their first column contains the date and the second one contains the daily value. How can I use the tick value for idexing?

Comment: Details added to answer.

Comment: This can be an example Date Time,SG [m]
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.80
2002-01-01,0.79

Comment: Details added to answer.